# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 400: "Request failed with status code 400"

Tags: node.js, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I want to upgrade my GPT 3 to GPT 3.5 turbo with Node Js. But i have a problem with that.

My ai.service.js code is:

```
const askAi = async (message) => {
  try {
    const openAIInstance = await _createOpenAIInstance()

    const response = await openAIInstance.createCompletion({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: message }]
    })

    const repliedMessage = response.data.choices[0].message.content

    return repliedMessage
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('', '', 'Ask AI Error: ' + err.message)
    return sendInternalError(err)
  }
}
```

But when i try to input message:

```
askAi('Suggest me a job position for Auto CAD user')
```

its return error:

```
Request failed with status code 400
```

I have already put the API correctly.

Comment: Verify You have access to the model by doing a GET on https://api.openai.com/v1/models

Comment: @AshokKumarSahoo so we should have an access to use GPT 3.5 Turbo? I mean not everyone can do. I have click that link, what should i input in username and password?

Comment: It uses a bearer token, please check here
https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models/list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

**You used the wrong function to get a completion for the given model.**

The function `createCompletion` works with the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api). In other words, the function `createCompletion` works with [GPT-3 models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3) (e.g., `text-davinci-003`) or [GPT base](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-base) models (e.g., `davinci-002`).

#### Solution

*Note: OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on August 16, 2023, and is a complete rewrite of the SDK. Among other things, there are changes in method names. See the `v3` to `v4` [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217).*

| Model | NodeJS function (SDK `v3`) | NodeJS function (SDK `v4`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 | openai.createChatCompletion | openai.chat.completions.create |
| GPT base and GPT-3 | openai.createCompletion | openai.completions.create |

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`: Change `createCompletion` to `createChatCompletion`

```
const askAi = async (message) => {
  try {
    const openAIInstance = await _createOpenAIInstance()

    const response = await openAIInstance.createChatCompletion({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: message }]
    })

    const repliedMessage = response.data.choices[0].message.content

    return repliedMessage
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('', '', 'Ask AI Error: ' + err.message)
    return sendInternalError(err)
  }
}
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`: Change `createCompletion` to `chat.completions.create`

*Note: There are also changes in extracting the message content in `v4`.*

```
const askAi = async (message) => {
  try {
    const openAIInstance = await _createOpenAIInstance()

    const response = await openAIInstance.chat.completions.create({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: message }]
    })

    const repliedMessage = response.choices[0].message.content

    return repliedMessage
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('', '', 'Ask AI Error: ' + err.message)
    return sendInternalError(err)
  }
}
```